How do I realign leaning door
I have a leaning door, which over the time has gotten worse and worse.
I want to realign it, or if not possible, mitigate the effects it has until I am able to afford a new one.
It is making it incredibly difficult to swing it open and close it, ruins the floor, and makes an annoying sound



Can you post a picture of how the hinges are attached to the other side?   It does seem like the problem is caused by loose hinges that need to be tighten or replaced.

Is the "lean" you're complaining about the door being slightly tilted to the right (1st pic)?  As crip659 notes, it does appear that the upper hinges are loose—or at least the door-to-frame gap is larger at the top.

I see what you mean by the "lean". The gap at the top of the door is tapered significantly, enough to make the latch not want to keep the door closed and since your door is very close to the floor, I can see how it will scrape the floor.
To fix the tapered gap will require a lot of work. A lot. I would opt for the simpler fix, but I will let you know what is needed to fix it so the gap is even acoss the top without buying a new door.
To start, the trim around the door will need to be removed from both sides. This will mean wall damage, and perhaps trim damage and at least painting. With the trim removed, you should be able to see the shims holding the door in its present location, they will be held in with nails, so it won't be easy to do for a novice. If you can get the shims out from the top and the middle on the hinge side, that is a good start. I am explaning this in a way that will not take any special carpentry tools, except for th necessities.
With the shims removed at the top and the middle, using a pry bar at the top corner of the latch side, pry the top over to close the gap where the shims are taken out. Stopping on occasion to check the gap at the top.
I almost forgot a very important step. Check the door for plumb at the jamb and see if the floor is level. If the floor is level. I will proceed where I left off. If the jamb is not plumb, and it will be one or the other, the gap at the top would not be there if the door was plumb and the floor was level. Or at least checking these things will give an indication of what is happening.
If the floor is out of level, the head (top) of the door should be too. It doesn't have to be, I have cut door jamb legs on one side to make the door head level when the floors were not level. If the door head IS level, then I will finish my original process.
Once the gap is more even at the top, the corner of the door at the floor should be raising too, fixing that problem, this will also fix the promblem, if any, with the strike, You may need to help the middle on the latch side, catch up with the top as you move it over. A drive block to protect the direct hit of a hammer will most likely be needed on the hinge side too, to help it all move over. Do not use a block and hammer only to drive it over. With starting it from the other side, at the top, a block and hammer will separate the top corner, not the best thing to happen, but recoverable, if not too bad. Reinstall the trim after cutting the shims off, making sure they are snug in place before cutting.
Whew! A lot of writing. I think what I have below, might be the best thing to do in your case. Much simpler.
Remove the door from the jamb, trim the bottom off a little. Maybe a 1/4" on the latch side, where it hits the floor to 0" on the hinge side. A SHARP hand plane, could do this or a hand saw with care, or a circular saw with more care, will work. Reset the door in place. Anything that is done to fix the gap at the top other than what I mentioned above, will most likely look as bad as the gap before anything was done.
As you get it where you need it to be, the gaps should finish out like you seen at first about an 1/8" (3mm). Add new shims where the old ones were taken out, and add more where the jamb was moved over, creating a new gap to fill with shims.
On the hinge side you will, most likely have some nails pop through, that will need to be reset into the jamb again. A nail set will be good for this.
If the door head is not level, then you may want to get a reciprocating saw, or oscillating saw

If the hinges are loose, tighten them. That may need longer screws in some cases, particularly on top. If things have moved, sometimes it's tighten or even cut the mortise slightly deeper on top and shim the bottom a little. Doors do tend to sag over time since the hinges are fighting considerable leverage from the door's weight.
If the door frame has distorted (you can check the diagonal measurements to see if they are equal, indicating it's a rectangle, or unequal, indicating it's now a parallelogram) you may want to check on why the house is moving, but that often takes the door adjustment from merely fiddling with the hinges to remove door, trim, and replace. I have had to do that where part of the house was jacked up after having sagged somewhat, with a door that must have been fitted with the sag already in play.
